# Error deserializing a json object starting with numbers

Tags: c#, json.net, getresponsestream

I'm obtaining a json string from a service call but I have an error trying to parse it with json.net. This is my service call:

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
using (var sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
{
   var json = sr.ReadToEnd();
   var address = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Address>(json);
}
```

The json variable is populated with a "strange" json result:

```
88
{"url":"http:\/\/www.google.com\/login?id=123&ref="}8|10
_srvtime1355861894
```

So the deserialization gives me the following error:

```
Error converting value 88 to type 'NameSpace.ClassName+Address'. Path '', line 1, position 2.
```

Do you have any idea about how to deserialize this kind of json object or, at least, how to instruct my WebRequest to not return those numbers (i guess they come from a chunked transmission)?

How can I handle the "\" present into the url returned into the json object? Do I simply replace it with an empty string?

Comment: If you go to the URL you're pulling from, does it return correctly formatted JSON data?  If not, then tell the website owner to stop sending bad JSON.

Comment: I have the same result when posting to the service with fiddler